# hello im hungarian i need help why blockcain stil me unconfirmed 4 day i have problem no can get block hash

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

how much days need wait when get confirmed

https://blockchain.info/tx/6bc53b5a388c9de4b5460afb7e1d54d44c2eb2001f879f871056207c6b9b0b39